# Jquery: cálculos com máscara de moeda real e soma de datas

Tags: jquery

Estou com uma tela pronta.
Mas há alguns ajustes que não estou conseguindo resolver.

Um deles é o calculo de valores com a máscara de Real.
Sem ela, funciona perfeitamente. Com ela o resultado fica Nan (o campo "Valor" recebe o mesmo e calcula para "Provisão royalties franchising", "Provisão fundo propaganda" e "Provisão royalties franchising").
A data está somando, mas com resultados malucos (a "Data da emissão" calcula para "1º vencimento", "2º vencimento" e "3º vencimento").

Estou mexendo o dia todo nisso e tentei adicionar o links dos scripts, mas não consegui.

Essa é a máscara para o Real (* maskMoney plugin for jQuery * http://plentz.github.com/jquery-maskmoney/) e esta é a mascara para data (jQuery Mask Plugin v1.14.10 // github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin).

Segue o que consegui fazer até o momento.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /****** Função percentual ******/
  function funcao_percentual(valor_1, destino, percentual) {
    $(valor_1).on("click", function() {
      $(destino).val('');
    });

    function arredondar(valor, casas) {
      var novo = Math.round(valor * Math.pow(10, casas)) / Math.pow(10, casas);
      return (novo);
    }

    $(valor_1).blur(function() {
      valor = $(this).val();
      porcentagem = percentual; // PORCENTAGEM A SER ADICIONADA
      total = (parseFloat((valor * porcentagem) / 100));
      $(destino).val(arredondar(total, 2));
    });
  }

  /****** Função subtrair ******/
  function funcao_subtrair(valor_1, valor_2, inicio, destino) {
    $(inicio).on("click", function() {
      $(destino).val('');
    });

    function arredondar(valor, casas) {
      var novo = Math.round(valor * Math.pow(10, casas)) / Math.pow(10, casas);
      return (novo);
    }

    $(inicio).blur(function() {
      valor_1_v = $(valor_1).val();
      valor_2_v = $(valor_2).val();
      total = (parseFloat((valor_1_v - valor_2_v)));
      $(destino).val(arredondar(total, 2));
    });
  }

  /****** Função calcular a data ******/
  function funcao_calcular_data(data_inicial, data_final, dias) {
    $(data_inicial).blur(function() {
      $(data_inicial).on("click", function() {
        $(data_final).val('');
      });

      var data_ini = $(data_inicial).val();

      var date = new Date(data_ini);
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + dias);
      var futDate = date.getDate() + "/" + date.getMonth() + "/" + date.getFullYear();


      $(data_final).val(futDate);
    });
  }

  /****** Percentual de Provisão - Royalties (franchising) ******/
  funcao_percentual("#valor", "#provisao_royalties_franchising", 39.85)

  /****** Percentual de Provisão Fundo Propaganda ******/
  funcao_percentual("#valor", "#provisao_fundo_propaganda", 3)

  /****** Subtração de Provisão - Royalties ( franchising) ******/
  funcao_subtrair("#provisao_royalties_franchising", "#provisao_fundo_propaganda", "#valor", "#provisao_royalties_franchising_2")

  /****** 1º vencimento ******/
  funcao_calcular_data("#data_emissao", "#1_venc", 28)

  /****** 2º vencimento ******/
  funcao_calcular_data("#data_emissao", "#2_venc", 42)

  /****** 3º vencimento ******/
  funcao_calcular_data("#data_emissao", "#3_venc", 56)


});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#data_emissao').mask('00/00/0000');
  $('#vencimento').mask('00/00/0000');
  $('#1_venc').mask('00/00/0000');
  $('#2_venc').mask('00/00/0000');
  $('#3_venc').mask('00/00/0000');
  $('#data_emissao_2').mask('00/00/0000');
  $('#vencimento_2').mask('00/00/0000');
  $('#data_emissao_3').mask('00/00/0000');
  $('#vencimento_3').mask('00/00/0000');
});

$(function() {
  $(".valor").maskMoney({
    symbol: 'R$ ',
    showSymbol: true,
    thousands: '.',
    decimal: ',',
    symbolStay: true
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




<div class="row">


  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Data da emissão</label>
      <div class="input-group date date-picker" data-date="">
        <div class="input-group date">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
                   <button class="btn default" type="button">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                   </button>
                  </span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="data_emissao" id="data_emissao">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Tipo</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Tipo" name="tipo" id="tipo" value="" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Nº nota fiscal</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Nº nota fiscal" name="num_nf" id="num_nf" value="" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Razão social</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Razão social" name="razao_social" id="razao_social" value="" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Valor</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Valor" name="valor" id="valor" value="" class="form-control valor" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Vencimento</label>
        <div class="input-group date date-picker" data-date="">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
                   <button class="btn default" type="button">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                   </button>
                  </span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vencimento" id="vencimento">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Forma de pagamento</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Forma de pagamento" name="forma_pgto" id="forma_pgto" value="" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Descrição</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Descrição" name="descricao" id="descricao" value="" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">1º vencimento</label>
        <div class="input-group date">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
                   <button class="btn default" type="button">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                   </button>
                  </span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="1_venc" id="1_venc" readonly>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">2º vencimento</label>
        <div class="input-group date">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
                   <button class="btn default" type="button">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                   </button>
                  </span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="2_venc" id="2_venc" readonly>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">3º vencimento</label>
        <div class="input-group date">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
                   <button class="btn default" type="button">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                   </button>
                  </span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="3_venc" id="3_venc" readonly>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Data da emissao</label>
        <div class="input-group date date-picker" data-date="">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
                   <button class="btn default" type="button">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                   </button>
                  </span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="data_emissao_2" id="data_emissao_2">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Provisão royalties franchising</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Provisão royalties franchising" name="provisao_royalties_franchising" id="provisao_royalties_franchising" value="" class="form-control valor" readonly />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Provisão fundo propaganda</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Provisão fundo propaganda" name="provisao_fundo_propaganda" id="provisao_fundo_propaganda" value="" class="form-control valor" readonly />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Nº documento</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Nº documento" name="num_doc" id="num_doc" value="" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Valor</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Valor" name="valor_2" id="valor_2" value="" class="form-control valor" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Vencimento</label>
        <div class="input-group date date-picker" data-date="">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
                   <button class="btn default" type="button">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                   </button>
                  </span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vencimento_2" id="vencimento_2">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Provisão royalties franchising</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Provisão royalties franchising" name="provisao_royalties_franchising_2" id="provisao_royalties_franchising_2" value="" class="form-control valor" readonly />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Nº nota fiscal</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Nº nota fiscal" name="num_nf_2" id="num_nf_2" value="" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Data de emissão</label>
        <div class="input-group date date-picker" data-date="">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
                   <button class="btn default" type="button">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                   </button>
                  </span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="data_emissao_3" id="data_emissao_3">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Valor</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Valor" name="valor_3" id="valor_3" value="" class="form-control valor" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Vencimento</label>
        <div class="input-group date date-picker" data-date="">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
                   <button class="btn default" type="button">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                   </button>
                  </span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vencimento_3" id="vencimento_3">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Xml</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Xml" name="xml" id="xml" value="" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Visto arquivo</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Visto arquivo" name="visto_arquivo" id="visto_arquivo" value="" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```